# Why node js doesn't exit after promise call

Tags: node.js

In the following code:

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}

sleep(10000);
```

Why NodeJS doesn't exit immediately? What causes the Promise to be waited for?

I thought I needed `await sleep(10000)` - but this gives an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nodejs waits for timers that are still active before exiting.  You can tell it to NOT wait for a timer by calling `.unref()` on the timer object itself.

So, it's not actually the promise it is waiting for, but rather the timer it is waiting for.

Internally, node.js keeps a reference count of the number of open timers that have not been `.unref()` and will not exit until that count (among other things) gets to zero.

---

Here's a couple excerpts from the [node.js doc for timers](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_class_timeout):

**Class: Timeout**

> By default, when a timer is scheduled using either setTimeout() or setInterval(), the Node.js event loop will continue running as long as the timer is active. Each of the Timeout objects returned by these functions export both timeout.ref() and timeout.unref() functions that can be used to control this default behavior.

**timeout.unref()**

> When called, the active Timeout object will not require the Node.js event loop to remain active. If there is no other activity keeping the event loop running, the process may exit before the Timeout object's callback is invoked. Calling timeout.unref() multiple times will have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `unref()` function for timers in node - https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_timeout_unref

> When called, the active `Timeout` object will not require the Node.js event loop to remain active. If there is no other activity keeping the event loop running, the process may exit before the `Timeout` object's callback is invoked.

You can create a timeout and call the `unref()` function on it - this will prevent node from staying alive if the only thing it is waiting for is the timeout.

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms).unref();
    });
}
```

As a side note, the same `unref` function can also be used for `setTimeout` calls.

---

As correctly noted by [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47312280/why-node-js-doesnt-exit-after-promise-call/47312319#47312319), it is not the promise that is keeping node alive, it is the timeout.